# Is there a way for me to run something when the user finishes resizing a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouse

The user can resize the JFrame by clicking and dragging their mouse on the corner of the window. I want to run some code after the user finishes resizing the JFrame, i.e. releases their mouse.

I have tried to use `javax.swing.Timer` with a delay of around 400 milliseconds to listen for resize events and run something when the timer finishes, however, this approach is unreliable because the code will run when you hold down the mouse button and keep the mouse at the same position.

Below is what I have tried:

```java
private final Timer resizeTimer = new Timer(400, null);

public Gui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    resizeTimer.setRepeats(false);
    resizeTimer.addActionListener(e -> { 
        // ...
    });
    // other JFrame code...
    frame.getRootPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if (resizeTimer.isRunning()) {
                resizeTimer.restart();
            } else {
                resizeTimer.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Small view of layout:

[image]

Layout when expanded:

[image]

Comment: You could compare the size of the window when `componentResized` starts and before you run what ever needs to be executed

Comment: *"I want to run some code after the user finishes resizing the JFrame"* What code? If it has anything to do with repainting the GUI, those methods will be called automatically.

Comment: I want to reposition some elements. Since I'm not using a LayoutManager (Since I'm doing a quick project I'm not too keen on learning them yet) I have to set the boundaries of the elements after resizing.

Comment: *"Since I'm not using a LayoutManager"* Ah .. the best, most robust (also possibly quickest) way to solve this is to use layouts. I might help with that, as can many others, including @MadProgrammer. Provide ASCII art (or simple drawing) of the GUI at default size and once resized to give extra width and height.

Comment: *I want to reposition some elements.* - and this is precisely why you should be using a layout manager.

Comment: *"Since I'm doing a quick project I'm not too keen on learning them yet"* - So, instead of learning/using the API which would solve your problems, you want to waste your time reproducing the work that they do (and which was designed and developed through hundreds if not thousands of developer hours) yourself?

Comment: You might also want to consider having a look at https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-swing/coalesce-events.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"you want to waste your time reproducing the work that they do (and which was designed and developed through hundreds if not thousands of developer hours) yourself?"* **OP:** Note also the three words related to 'you' in that sentence? It harks to an important point. The help offered so far has been from 3 of the top 6 [up-voted providers of answers for Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers), and the **top three** [up-voted providers of answers for layout managers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/layout-manager/topusers) on SO - we're not likely to be ..

Comment: .. spending time trying to reinvent layouts because some newbie wants to skip that learning task! So .. back to you, really. Do you want to know how to do this task with layouts? Then, as mentioned earlier, but a little louder .. ***Provide ASCII art (or simple drawing) of the GUI at default size and once resized to give extra width and height.***

Comment: Hey everyone, apologies for the late reply. I didn't know that layout managers were as crucial as you describe them to be. So, I'll be happy to use them. Should I edit my original post to add the ASCII art in, or should I link it as a Pastebin?

Comment: Never mind, I think it would be more convenient for me to use screenshots instead of ASCII art, so here's what the GUI should look like at default size: [screenshot](https://flying-in.space/javeFaxHxb.png?key=DPmYnUbydpRFeJ). And resized: [screenshot](https://flying-in.space/fVoiThjQC9.png?key=1TvyOy8xssbnjr).

Comment: I'd probably use a `GridBagLayout` for that. The trick is to realise that each cell of the layout (e.g. containing a button or a text field) might span more than a single column or row.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.